# What text (in English) should I use when asking the user to overwrite a document?

Tags: interface, messagebox, human-readable

I write a lot of applications in C# and I'm trying to sew up some holes in my standard practices.

Specifically, I'm trying to decide on the best text to use in a message box, and I thought I'd ask the StackOverflow community since I believe that many opinions are always better than one.

What I have currently is:

> "Document XXX.docx already exists. Okay to overwrite?"
>
> Buttons for; Yes, No and Cancel

I'm really interested to see which examples turn out to be the most popular.

There are no limits on the style used; formal, casual, humourous, etc. All suggestions are welcome. Aim to err safely within political correctness though.

On a small side note: It would also be great, but by no means essential, to consider that the same text could also be suitable for a command line program.

Please note: English language only please. For other languages, please raise a new question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about user interface design. This question would probably be more suitable over at [User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) but it needs to be reworded to be less opinion-based.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Rink. Will do :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I like to see a bit more context and slightly different wording.  Something like:

```
"<existing document name>" already exists in "<destination path>".
Would you like to replace it (Y/N)?
```

or perhaps with even more information:

```
"<existing document name>" (<bytes>) (<date modified>) already exists in
"<destination path>".
Would you like to replace it with file of size <new bytes>, last modified
<new date modified> (Y/N)?
```

I think "*replace*" is a bit more clear than "overwrite" - and (speculation) may translate into other languages, and maintain the intended meaning more often.

...and one last option with new file name/location info:

```
"<existing document name>" (<bytes>) (<date modified>) already exists in
"<destination path>".
Would you like to replace it with file "<new file name>" in "<new path>" of 
size <new bytes>, last modified <new date modified> (Y/N)?
```

This last one would probably just show a temp file / buffer location for an initial file save--but it is reusable, and **more meaningful** when doing a file copy.

Hope you find one of these useful.

Cheers,
Hans

Comment: also note that you may appeal to [english.stackexchange.com](http://english.stackexchange.com/) for additional guidance on all things of wordy flavor

Comment: Thank for the advice, Hans. Will do. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Title: Overwrite?

"XXX.docx exists. 
Would you like to overwrite XXX.docx?"

Buttons: Overwrite, Keep, Panic
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solutions are usually best, for example windows user might find it familiar to see a message :

[image]

He has 3 options :

- Replace
- Abort action x3
- Create with a new name